# Compiler Error when using find() on a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, find

I am trying have a method that takes a string and will give the character frequency of each character and storing it in a 2D array or a 2D vector. I keep getting a compiler error when I run the code and I am not sure what it is saying. I have done some research on the error and I still have not been able to solve the issue. I think there has to be some sort of header missing or something because the class be referenced is not mine.

```
 vector<pair<char, int>> CaesarCypher::charFreqGen(string inputFileName)
 {
     string input = GetInputString(inputFileName);
     vector<pair<char, int>> output;

     for (auto c : input)
     {
         auto it = find(output.begin(), output.end(),[=](const pair<int, char>& p) {return p.first == c; });
         if (it != output.end())
             it->second++;
         else
             output.push_back(std::make_pair(c, 1));
     }
     return output;
  }
```

Here is the error that I am recieving:

```
 Error  1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::pair<char,int>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3026    1   PA1_CaesarCypher
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `std::find_if` if you are searching an element with a predicate function. See the documentation of `std::find` and `std::find_if` on http://en.cppreference.com/w/:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Answer (score 1):

You declared the vector as:

```
vector<pair<char, int>> output;
```

but then when using `find`:

```
auto it = find(output.begin(), output.end(),[=](const pair<int, char>& p) {return p.first == c; });
```

You inverted the types of the pair, it should be:

```
auto it = find(output.begin(), output.end(),[=](const pair<char, int>&p) {return p.first == c; });
```

EDIT: As nosid said, you have to use `find_if` to use a predicate.

Comment: What `std::find` with lambda ? :P